# Como puedo manipular varias filas de un grid view?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, gridview

estoy trabajando en windows form y tengo un gridview que jala datos desde un excel para luego actualizar dichos datos a una web pero solo puedo hacerla uno por uno. Aunque marque todas con ctrl + click solo manda datos de la ultima fila que haya seleccionado aunque haya marcados todos.

Como puedo hacer que todas las filas que seleccione manden los datos?

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Debes mostrar el codigo que usas, porque muy probablemente tu problemas este en el codigo. usar el boton [edit] y agrega el mismo a la pregunta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existe una funcion del control `DataGridView` que sirve para saber las `rows` seleccionadas. Se llama `DataGridViewSelectedRowCollection` y sirve para hacer exactamente lo que necesitas.

Por ejemplo...

```
  private void Button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridViewSelectedRowCollection Seleccionados = dataGridView1.SelectedRows;

        foreach (DataGridViewRow item in Seleccionados)
        {
            string id = item.Index.ToString();
            MessageBox.Show(id);
        }
    }
```

Con esta función que se ejecuta desde el click de un botón te devuelve a un `MessageBox` el indice del `row`. Imagino que con esto te es mas que suficiente para lo que vos necesitas.

Cualquier cosita respondo rápido!

No te olvides de marcas como la respuesta correcta en caso que te halla funcionado

Comment: Esto fue de gran ayuda!

Comment: Perfecto, marcala como la respuesta correcta para ayudar a mas gente, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

El control `GridView` no permite `seleccion multiple`, no al menos con el uso del `ctrl + click` para conseguir la seleccion de varias rows deberias agregar una columna con `checkbox`

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="chk" runat="server"/>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Entonces desde codigo podras iterar las rows y conocer la seleccion multiple en base a la columna de checks

```
foreach (var row in GridView1.Rows)
{
    CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("chk");

    if (chk != null && chk.Checked)
    {
        //codigo
    }

}
```

[Select and delete multiple rows in ASP.Net Gridview control](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Select-and-delete-multiple-rows-in-ASP.Net-Gridview-control.aspx)